# how to figure out trend per unique key. dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 2 cols

```
ColA| ColB 
D 2 
D 12 
D 15 
A 20 
A 40 
A 60 
C 60 
C 55 
C 70 
C 45 
L 45 
L 23 
L 10 
L 5
```

RESULT/Output would be

```
D UP
A UP
C FLAT
L Down
```

Where UP is result of adding up all the relevant Weights: each successive weight for each key, must be less than the previous weight.

Example
for UP you must have

Comment: How you define the flat ?

Comment: not strictly UP or DOWN

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple technique, might not suit for all cases i.e :

```
def sum_t(x):
    # Compare the value with previous value
    m = x > x.shift() 
    # If all of them are increasing then return Up
    if m.sum() == len(m)-1:
        return 'UP'
    # if all of them are decreasing then return Down
    elif m.sum() == 0:
        return 'DOWN'
    # else return flat
    else:
        return 'FLAT'

df.groupby('ColA')['ColB'].apply(sum_t)
```

Output:

```
ColA
A      UP
C    FLAT
D      UP
L    DOWN
Name: ColB, dtype: object
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly happents at `m` variable. what does `m.sum() `returns?. I'm new to programming.

Comment: m is a boolean mask, with the help of shift I'm check if the current value is greater than previous value. After summing them if the value is less than or equal to the group size then its up if its 0 then its Down.

Answer (score 3):

Using `diff` and `crosstab`

```
s=df.groupby('ColA').ColB.diff().dropna()#Dropna since the first value for all group is invalid 
pd.crosstab(df.ColA.loc[s.index],s>0,normalize = 'index' )[True].map({1:'Up',0:'Down'}).fillna('Flat')
Out[100]:
ColA
A      Up
C    Flat
D      Up
L    Down
Name: True, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Variation to @Dark's idea, I would first calculate `GroupBy` + `diff` and then use `unique` before feeding to a custom function.

Then use logic based on `min` / `max` values.

```
def calc_label(x):
    if min(x) >= 0:
        return 'UP'
    elif max(x) <= 0:
        return 'DOWN'
    else:
        return 'FLAT'

res = df.assign(C=df.groupby('ColA').diff().fillna(0))\
        .groupby('ColA')['C'].unique()\
        .apply(calc_label)

print(res)

ColA
A      UP
C    FLAT
D      UP
L    DOWN
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `numpy.polyfit` in a custom `def`

This way you can tweak the gradiant you would class as 'FLAT'

```
def trend(x, flat=3.5):
    m = np.polyfit(np.arange(1, len(x)+1), x, 1)[0]
    if abs(m) < flat:
        return 'FLAT'
    elif m > 0:
        return 'UP'
    return 'DOWN'

df.groupby('ColA')['ColB'].apply(np.array).apply(trend)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution by applying linear regression on each ID associated points and specifying the trend by slope of id associated point in 2 dimensional space

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
def slope(x,min_slope,max_slope):
    reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(np.arange(len(x),x))
    slope =  reg.coef_[0][0]
    if slope < min_slope:
        return 'Down'
    if slope > max_slope:
         return 'Up'
    else 'Flat'
min_slope = -1
max_slope = 1
df['slopes'] = df.groupby('ColA').apply(lambda x: slope(x['ColB'],min_slope,max_slope))
```